# Tableau edit Shapes folder path

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to know if it is somehow possible to only edit the path to the Shapes folder from the default Tableau Repo.
I know the path to the entire repo can be edited within the software but I am only interested in the Shapes folder.

I would like to have it stored in a shared drive, and eventually doing the same thing with the Preferences.tps file. I don't want to place the entire repo on the shared folder mainly because the datasources folder has some customizations that can't be shared.

Best,
Max

Comment: have you tried using a symlink on a mac, or a shortcut on Windows for the Shape folder?

Comment: no I didn't... and now that I have it works very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using a symlink on a mac, or a shortcut on Windows for the Shape folder?

Thank you Alex...